# Is there a way to replace a global swatch color by dragging another object on top of it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]
Hi SE

I have a set of global RGB colors in my Swatch palette and I need to update some of them with a new hex code. But I can't access the hex input in the Swatch Options, so my only option is to input the RGB definition.

Is there a way to replace the Swatch color by dragging another object on top of it (like you're able with Graphic Styles) ?

Thanks and HNY :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes.

Drag from the **Color Panel** and hold the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key down when you "drop" the new color..

[image]

You *must* drag from the Color Panel. 
You can't drag the *object* because that will default to creating a pattern swatch.

Comment: Wow, that was sneaky  Thanks Scott 